Multi Node GPU Utilization with Docker for Machine Learning Platform
My home lab server has two nodes, let's call them Node A and Node B. Node A has 4 GPUs and Node B has 2 GPUs. How can I combine that computational power with Docker containers for machine learning/deep learning tools? If there's a better solution, I would love to know. :)
With my limited knowledge of computer systems, I installed Docker on Node A and ran a container for a machine learning platform (Jupyter container) to utilize the largest computational power that I have. However, with this approach, I can only utilize a maximum of 4 GPUs from Node A. Is there a way to combine both resources? Ideally, when I execute nvidia-smi inside the Jupyter container, it should detect 6 GPUs, which come from both Node A and Node B.

What you are looking for is distributed training, but it does not work the way you want it, GPUs are always local and cannot be "shared" via the network. Also docker does not have these capabilities.

I understand. Thank you very much. But, I'm curious. Is it possible to deploy something like agent container to Node B which could be detected using Node A?
